# ChannelGrabber Issues: Identical SKU's for Variants

Tags: magento-1.9, product, product-list, inventory, sku

I'm having an interesting issue with a new retail shop that's being set up. At the moment my client has a vast name for themselves on ebay and amazon and are looking to expand on this. As such, we've been building a magento shop for a while. After thinking that we were ready for launch it was picked up that some of the products weren't working the way they were supposed to. In fact, A LOT of the products weren't linked into channel grabber at all.

After a little playing around we found that the issue is to do with SKU's and the way the product variations have been laid out in channel grabber.

An example would be: We have a shirt. But the shirt has both colours and sizes listed all under the one sku for the shirt.

This wouldn't be an issue but on the retail site we're looking to SPLIT the different colours into different products.

So each colour for the shirt on magento will end up using the same sku for the configurable product listing which leads to duplicate entries.

What is the best way to work around this problem? I know editting and removing the ability for sku's to be unique is a nono. That's a given.

There are literally thousands of products so i'm trying to find out the best way to lower the amount of time required to set this up correctly. I know i can at least make new listings and split up the old ones.. are there any other ways to go about making this work that anyones had experience with?